# Fields in the web page behaves differently during automation. is it possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Web Page info: The page has the calendar field and date picker fields.
If I click the page manually date and calendar fields are filled with data but If I click the page through automation scripts,date and calendar fields are empty.

Can anyone explain? why this could happened?

Comment: Give the url please

Comment: Give the url or add the HTML please!

Comment: Not possible brother.I should not share...Hope you understand@Rajagopalan

Comment: How you verify the element is empty?

Comment: just observed the fields in the page manually while running the script